# Count method sql class not working in php

Tags: php, sql, class

I'm trying to use an object to count the number of records in my db that meet certain criteria but I can't work out how to make it work. The following code is my count method inside my db connection class:

```
//Counts the total number of records and returns integer
public function totalCount($fieldname, $tablename, $where = "") 
{
    $q = "SELECT count(".$fieldname.") FROM "
    . $tablename . " " . $where;

    $result = $this->mysqli->query($q);
    $count = 0;

    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $count = $row[0];
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

This code is outside the class:

```
 //New instantiation
 $mydb = new myDBC();

 //Count the number of transactions for the user...
 $count = $mydb->totalCount('amount','transactions','WHERE userid = 13');

 //output the number of transactions for the user
 print $count;
```

For some reason this always displays 0, even though my db has thousands of records inside it that should be counted. Grateful for any pointers as to where my syntax isn't right.

Thanks

Comment: I find it interesting that you require the user of your interface to pass in the `WHERE` identifier with the where clause.

Comment: I was trying to make it open enough to allow for GROUP BY etc. I might develop it further in the longer term but I'm quite new to OOP in PHP so am trying to learn first.. Please correct me if I'm heading in the wrong direction!

Comment: I'd probably add additional parameters for `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and `ORDER BY` as they serve a different function. You can set default values for those parameters, and check if the user of your interface actually passed anything or not. This discussion is kind of off-topic though.

Comment: Makes sense! Once I get this working I'll do that - Thanks

Comment: An even better idea would be to create an SQL Statement class, that encapsulates all these different parts of an SQL statement. Then pass that to your totalCount function. You should take a look at PHP's `PDO` object. It is already an object oriented interface for dealing with a database. You could wrap/extend it to add your desired functionality.

Comment: Is this part of a class with a member called `mysqli`? Evidenced by `$this->mysqli->query`. Also, have you verified that this query actually returns something besides `0` outside of PHP (like PhpMyAdmin or whatever interface you use to query your database).

Comment: use mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array() instead of  $this->mysqli->query() and mysqli_fetch_array();

Comment: Isn't mysql_query being depreciated?

Comment: I think part of the issue is the mix of `$this->mysqli->query()` and `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Comment: It is part of a mysqli query - that connects to the db as follows:     new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);   
 if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
     echo "Error MySQLi: ("&nbsp. $this->mysqli->connect_errno 
     . ") " . $this->mysqli->connect_error;
     exit();
  }
    $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); 
 }

Comment: You might need to pass that `mysqli` instance to `mysqli_fetch_array`, but I'm not sure (I thought it uses the last used connection if not specified).

Comment: Nevermind, you can't pass the connection to mysqli_fetch_array - makes sense because you're passing the result object. I wasn't sure if the result contained all record data, or if maintained a connection to stream records from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this method returns zero for all tables/fields or you tested only

`$mydb->totalCount('amount','transactions','WHERE userid = 13');`?

The `count` counts only `NOT NULL` values. To count all records pass asterisk to the `count` function: `count(*)`

Comment: Thanks - the * solved it... And helped me spot a careless spelling mistake :/

Answer (score 0):

Query execution returning false and it's not going inside if conditions thats why count is always zero

Answer (score 0):

You can use prepared statement to prepare the query and then execute it. And, I don't think that it is essential to pass a field as argument to `COUNT`.

Anyway, as per your question, this would make a better query.

```
$q = 'SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM ' . $strTable . ' WHERE ' . $strCond;
```

Again, since you are using MySQLi, use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).